# How do I use the user chosen excel file in the area i indicated

Tags: pysimplegui

How do I use the chosen excel file. I am having a hard time choosing the chosen Excel File under layouts. On the output_num I am trying to divide by 8 in order to determine what if statement should be executed.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import csv

sg.theme('DarkBlue')

binFile1=binFile2=binFile3=binFile4=binFile5=binFile6=binFile7=binFile8 = None
binFile9=binFile10=binFile11=binFile12=binFile13=binFile14=binFile15=binFile16 = None

layouts = [
    [   # Layout 0
        [sg.Text('How many driver bits do you need? (Enter a number between 1 and 71)')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN0-', expand_x=True, enable_events=True)],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT0-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', disabled=True, key='Prev 0'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 0')]],
    [   # Layout 1
        [sg.Text('Choose .CSV/Excel File')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN1-', expand_x=True), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Excel Files ONLY (.xlsx)", "*.xlsx"),))],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT1-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 2'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 2')]],
    [   # Layout 2
        [sg.Text('Please choose where you would like to export the .BIN files...')],
        [sg.Input(key='-IN2-', expand_x=True), sg.FolderBrowse()],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT2')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 3'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 3')]],
    [   # Layout 3
        [sg.Text('Please go back and verify your settings. \nIf everything looks correct, click Next >.')],
        [sg.Text('', size=(20, 1), key='-OUTPUT3-')],
        [sg.Button('< Prev', key='Prev 4'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Next >', key='Next 4')]],
    [   # Layout 4
        [sg.Text('Compilation Complete! \nYour files have been saved in your chosen directory.')],
        [sg.Text('Finish!', expand_x=True, justification='center')],
        [sg.Button('< Top', key='Top'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Exit')]],
]

layout = [[sg.Column(item, visible=(i==0), key=f'Column {i}') for i, item in enumerate(layouts)]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, enable_close_attempted_event=True)
column = 0

#output_num = -IN0- / 8

start_time = time.time()
init = True
linecnt = 0

def open_output_files(num_bytes):
    try:
        count = int(num_bytes)
    except ValueError:
        count = 16
    if not (0 <= count <= 15):
        count = 16
    return [open(f"{157+i}.bin", "wb") for i in range(count)]

open_output_files(5)

def show(step):
    global column
    window[f'Column {column}'].update(visible=False)
    column += step
    window[f'Column {column}'].update(visible=True)
    window.refresh()
    window.move_to_center()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        if column in (0, 5):
            break
        else:
            show(-1)
    elif event in ('Exit', 'Finish!'):
        break
    elif event.startswith("Prev"):
        show(-1)
    elif event.startswith("Next"):
        show(+1)
    elif event == 'Top':
        show(-5)

with open("Use user chosen CSV") as vecfile:
    vectors = csv.reader(vecfile, delimiter = ',')
    for vec in vectors:
        if(linecnt < 0):
            next
        else:
            temp_vec = ''
            for i in range(0,72):
                temp_vec += vec[i]
                #print(temp_vec)
            temp_vec = temp_vec.translate({ord(x): '0' for x in ['Z', 'X', 'H', 'L']})
            vec_str = temp_vec + ''  #ADD PADDED 0'S TO MAKE OVERALL NUMBER OF VECTORS % 8 = 0
            #print(vec_str)

            byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2) # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT # OF BYTES REQUIRED FOR BURNIN SETUP
            byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)
            byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)
            byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
            byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)
            byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
            byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
            byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
            byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
            #byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)
            #byte11 = int(vec_str[87:79:-1],2)
            #byte12 = int(vec_str[95:87:-1],2)
            #byte13 = int(vec_str[103:95:-1],2)
            #byte14 = int(vec_str[111:103:-1],2)
            #byte15 = int(vec_str[119:111:-1],2)
            #byte16 = int(vec_str[127:119:-1],2)

            binFile1.write(byte1.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')) # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT # OF BYTES REQUIRED FOR BURNIN SETUP
            binFile2.write(byte2.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            binFile3.write(byte3.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            binFile4.write(byte4.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            binFile5.write(byte5.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            binFile6.write(byte6.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            binFile7.write(byte7.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            binFile8.write(byte8.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            binFile9.write(byte9.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            #binFile10.write(byte10.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            #binFile11.write(byte11.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            #binFile12.write(byte12.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            #binFile13.write(byte13.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            #binFile14.write(byte14.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            #binFile15.write(byte15.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
            #binFile16.write(byte16.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))


            binFile1.close() # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT # OF BYTES REQUIRED FOR BURNIN SETUP
            binFile2.close()
            binFile3.close()
            binFile4.close()
            binFile5.close()
            binFile6.close()
            binFile7.close()
            binFile8.close()
            binFile9.close()
            #binFile10.close()
            #binFile11.close()
            #binFile12.close()
            #binFile13.close()
            #binFile14.close()
            #binFile15.close()
            #binFile16.close()



window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find when the file to be open and write code by `case-if` statement, most of time, it is when an event generated, like a button clicked.

Following example show how to work on user chosen XLXS file after a button `Submit` clicked.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(key='-IN-'), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("All XLSX Files", "*.xlsx"), ))],
    [sg.Button('Submit')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        filename = values['-IN-']
        if Path(filename).is_file():    # Check if file exists or not
            """ Open user chosen xlsx file & do something here """
            print(filename)

window.close()
```

Comment: Maybe `os.path.isfile(path)` better.

Comment: EDIT - my previous comment was about os.path.exists as an option... and Jason rightfully suggested isfile as a better solution.  I pulled exists from code where I was checking a path (i.e. folder) exists, not a file. os.path.isfile is indeed the right one to use for files.